# не создается динам. компонент, нужно перезаходить в форму

Tags: c++, c++builder, radstudio, компоненты

создал динамический компонент, в котором при нажатии создаю на этой же форме другой динамический компонент на этой же форме. И только при повторном заходе на форму появляется этот компонент
код такой

```
void __fastcall TTabbedForm::TabItem5Click(TObject *Sender)
{
TabItem13 = new TTabItem(TabControl4);
  TabItem13->Parent = TabControl4;
  TabItem13->Text = "add new account";
 TabItem13->OnClick = TabbedForm->TabItem13Click;
    TabbedForm->TabControl4->ActiveTab= 0;
}
```

вот создал компонент.

```
void __fastcall TTabbedForm::TabItem13Click(TObject *Sender)
{
      TabItem13->Free();
     ned1 = new TEdit(TabControl4);
    ned1->Parent =  TabControl4;
    ned1->Width = 100;
}
```

Но при нажатии на кнопку он не создается. нужно перезайти в форму. почему так????? в чем может быть проблема?
возможно влияет то что я пытаюсь создать на том месте где был первый компонент который я удаляю TabItem13->Free() при нажатии на него?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кто же уничтожает компонент, находясь в обработчике события этого компонента? Для уничтожения Вам нужно послать асинхронное сообщение форме и форма уничтожит этот объект позже

```
MESSAGE void __fastcall WMDelayDestroy(TMessage &msg);

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP
  MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_DELAY_DESTROY, TMessage, WMDelayDestroy);
END_MESSAGE_MAP(TComponent)

void __fastcall TTabbedForm::TabItem13Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  PostMessage(Handle, WM_DELAY_DESTROY, (WPARAM)TabItem13, 0);
  ned1 = new TEdit(TabControl4);
  ned1->Parent =  TabControl4;
  ned1->Width = 100;
} 

void __fastcall TTabbedForm::WMDelayDestroy(TMessage &msg)
{
  ((TObject*)msg.WParam)->Free();
{
```

Comment: спасибо большое, я не сильно понял ваш код, что прописать в гугле чтоб почитать про это?

Comment: @Макс `c++ builder message handler`. Вот ссылка на сайт эмбаркадеры http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Declaring_a_New_Message-handling_Method